# Dynamic SSIS transforms building tables lists at run time

Tags: ssis

I'm looking for some pointers in creating an SSIS based workflow that reads a list of tables at run time from a database and then uses each of these as ADO inputs, selects specific columns from each table and then adds these to a staging area. I've had a quick play with the union task but was looking for some pointers in terms of direction to take ?

I can't seem to find anything on the net that does what I need and am not sure if SSIS can bend to suit my needs.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but the only method I can think of is a little convoluted.

You would need to use a "for each loop container" to loop through your list of tables & read each table name into an SSIS variable.

Within the "foreach":

- add a script task to build your actual query into another SSIS variable.
- add a data flow
- within the Data Flow use a source of "SQL Command from variable".
- do data flow "stuff"

I hope this makes some kind of sense? :-)

Comment: It's only possible if there's a table with source-dest column mappings

Comment: @makciook how would I reference such a table ?

Comment: @bhs - https://www.google.pl/search?q=map+columns+in+ssis+c%23&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:pl:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr - first two links

Comment: I ended up using a reference table containing table names to process, a sql task, a for each loop and cycled through each table populating a script output.